# Why are bali/sacrifices of non-Asuric animals & humans so satisfying to Kaali Mata?

Tags: devi, durga, shakti, shaktism, sacrifice

The most common sacrifice is the goat and the Buffalo/**Mahisha** is the second most common. Both are **Asuric**. Kali maa loves to receive the sacrifice of **Asuras** of any kind.

Do lion & tiger also have **asura nature, pravritti**?

Regarding human sacrifice it is like enemy king (usually a **non-dharmic person**). But what about other kinds of human sacrifice? Should the always persons be **non-Dharmic**?

If not, then why does Maa want their Bali? Sorry if I am mistaken and only Asura-nature animals & humans can be sacrificed

[image]

Comment: Your opinion is 100% against scripture. Please refrain from making such political comments. @Archit **She is the primodial mother... the supreme being... not anybody's daughter! She created Vishnu, Brahma and Shiva.... She is the destroyer of evil Asuras.**

Comment: **You completely missed "destroyer of evil Asuras".** She is the maintainer of Dharma. The evil asuras must be sacrificed & destroyed at all times. You are being like fanatical christian or Jew who hates sacrifice and Hinduism. Your morals are all from your western (christian) education in western-style (christian) schools with western (christian) style teachers and atmosphere. There are people in every religion like this who say **"it's out of context" or "it's not to be taken literally"** to make religions conform with modernity. All you people hate plurality & tradition

Comment: It obviously doesn't go with the basic logic, that an entity which is said to be Omnipotent, Omnipresent and Omniscient - eulogized with epithets like *Para-Brahman* (पर - ब्रह्म), such an entity will demand sacrifices of petulant creatures like humans, animals, etc.. We're basically a speck of useless dust in this multiversal Cosmos. Common sense dictates that people with avarice for eating non-veg foods, have created these rituals and interpolated all scriptures within the interstices of the Sanâtan Dharma to allow for and justify their own "benefits".

Comment: It shows our human devotion to the supreme when we sacrifice Asuras. It is a punya karma. **Human beings are not petulant specks of dust!! We have Aatmaa/ Soul, Karma, Dharma etc. Now you are definitely trolling.** Your thought is not your own... but liberal hatred you have grown up thinking is very good @Vivikta Getting upvoted by liberals is not going to make you look good. **It just shows you people have large number**

Comment: How many humans have you sacrificed?

Comment: I think it’s figuratively meant then people didn’t understand that and traditions got set in place that aren’t correct.